# Fan speed at maxium and kernel_task at more than 300% after changing the display assembly

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, cpu

I recently replaced my MacBook Pro's (mid-2012) display assembly. After the first boot, my fan speed is at maximum and kernel_task is at more than 300% which is affecting the responsiveness of the OS. I read somewhere that disconnecting the iSight camera cable can solve this problem and yes, it really does.

Is there a solution to this problem without disconnecting the iSight cable?

Battery status is "service battery". <kbd>Control</kbd> key is not working.

Comment: Are you certain you reconnected everything. You may have missed a sensor. Did you try an SMC reset? Did you have the battery and keyboard issue prior to the display replacement?

Comment: Also try [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262). The iSight camera is a USB device so if disconnecting a USB device fixing your problem, you either have an issue with the device or the USB bus causing CPU runaway.  Try plugging in an external USB device (like another webcam) or a disk and move some files back and forth.

Comment: Be sure to @ me when replying in comments.  This way we can be notified that you've replied.  Add additional details to the *original* question by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/380287/edit) it.